# I can't create a SELECT tag using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm not able to build a SELECT TAG HTML using AngularJS. Could someone help me? My problem is with the `ng-repeat` I guess.

I have a **Json** response like this:

```
[{
        "Unity": [
            {
                "Name": "ASD ALSKJD ASLKJ ASLD",
                "Code": "11106600"
            },
            {
                "Name": "AioPE PW pIOW DPOIUWD POFIWU PFOIW",
                "Code": "11106601"
            },
            {
                "Name": "APOIU Ppeoiupo8uepo8uwp IUPD FOIUS PFOISDU",
                "Code": "11106602"
            }
        ]
}]
```

My **Controller** is:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.url = 'pathtocontroller/controller.asp'; //the response of json is from here
        $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.Name = data.Name;
            $scope.Code = data.Code;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.response = 'Request failed';
            });
}
```

My **HTML** is:

```
<div class="grid-6-12" ng-controller='MyController'>
    <label>A label for unity <em class="formee-req">*</em></label>
    <select class="formee-small" ng-repeat="Name in Name">
        <option value=" {{Code}} ">{{Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a specific directive in Angular for implementing selects - [see the documentation here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)

As an example from the docs:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
      <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

**Important Note:** 
If you use this directive, and then view the generated HTML code, you will notice that the values of each generated `<option>` are integers 0, 1, 2,... This might throw you off, but you just need to know that Angular uses this value internally and if you refer to the model (`$scope.color` in the above example), it will contain the correct value.

So, in your case, you could do something like this (updated to match your controller setup):

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'pathtocontroller/controller.asp'; //the response of json is from here
    $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.data = data[0].Unity;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.response = 'Request failed';
        });
}
```

and then in your template:

```
<div class="grid-6-12" ng-controller="MyController">
    <label>A label for unity <em class="formee-req">*</em></label>
    <select ng-model="option" ng-options="row.Name as row.Code for row in data">
    Selected: {{ option }} <!-- just to show it is working -->
</select>
</div>
```

## Example

Here is a working example of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/eGCKa/2/

Comment: The value is random... <OPTION VALUE>

Comment: Okay, I updated the example code to something that should work with the API you are using. In any case, the essential answer to the original question is covered by the first line of my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: There are at least a couple of reasons why your fiddle doesn't work. Firstly, you need to set it up to use angular (with the various option on the left). Secondly, and most important, you are calling your API with a relative URL - `unidades/unidades-controler.asp`. This will only work on your development machine. Try my example there and see if it works.

Comment: Almost work! it lists now, but, I can see the name inside <option></option>, but I also need the Code

Comment: I need <option value="CODE">NAME</option>

Comment: you can always do it the dirty way, using ng-repeat on the option tag

Comment: Okay, that's simply a case of changing the ng-options to switch the two around, like `row.Code as row.Name for row in data`. Play with the fiddle and you'll be able to figure it out!

Comment: I did it, but inside tag OPTION the VALUE is always 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...

Comment: What you told me to do changes <option>`this`</option>

Comment: @UderMoreira, regarding the VALUE, see my additional "important note" I have added to the answer. Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is a bit off:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'pathtocontroller/controller.asp'; //the response of json is from here
    $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.returnedData = data[0].Unity[0]; // or however you access the Unity object
    }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.response = 'Request failed';
        });
}
```

Then adjust your html:

```
<select class="formee-small" ng-repeat="item in returnedData">
    <option value=" {{item.Code}} ">{{item.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its missing a lot... like a controller.

Comment: the controller is ConsultaUnidadesSolicitantes